# Auditing ads served on websites for malware / badware - Does such a service exist?

Tags: advertising, service, malware, detection

We recently had a bit of a scare on one of the web properties we administer.

One of the 3rd party advertisers that we use had an advertiser who was distributing malware.

Although this only took place for a day, the effect was dramatic. Google blocked our outbound links from google, chrome / firefox and safari all showed a message stating that the website the user is visiting has been found to be distributing malware.

Although this passed quickly, after disabling the offending advertisers, we would like to prevent this from ever happening in the future.

So the question is as follows:

Is there a service which audits the ads served on a website for malware / badware? We have done a few google searches and were unable to find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [HackAlert SafeImpression](http://www.armorize.com/index.php?link_id=SafeImpression) from Armorize Malware. I've never used it, but if I understood well your problem, this may be worth a look.

Comment: Yep, this is the one i stumbled upon myself. Thanks!